# Rotating problem with an object going along the curve in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a problem with my object on a curve, it works, it goes along the curve, works fine except that this object is rotating around its axis, I don't want this behavior

[image: a problem itself]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control the tilt, you'll need to align a second axis using the first as pivot.

You can align to the curve's normal which is controlled by the tilt of control points:

[image]

[image]

or, in this case, you can align up ($+Z$) using the vector $\left(0, 0, 1\right)$:

[image]

[image]